# i am getting this error when i use npx command Error: EPERM: operation not permitted,

Tags: wordpress, reactjs, npm, wordpress-gutenberg

I am trying to install [create-guten-block](https://github.com/ahmadawais/create-guten-block) package using this command `npx create-guten-block my-block` but i couldn't install it.

my node version: 10.15.1

npm version: 6.4.1

i am getting following error.  what i am doing wrong i am following documentation. 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this command and try again:

```
npm cache clean --force
```